# setuptools and passing options to dependencies

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setuptools

I'm trying to package a module for pypi and I have mercurial as one of the dependencies.

The target machines may or may not have build tools so I'd like to install mercurial with the --pure option in place, but I couldn't find a way to instruct setup.py to install the dependencies in a specified manner. Other than installing the deps separately, I couldn't find a way to do this.

The best I have so far is 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/turbogears/t9rZAMSj_NQ

Which although very clever is a bit of a hack. Like person in the link I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

---

Google makes it exceptionally hard to search for flags, switches and specific options since it doesn't support punctuation, so the search was being extra un-helpful.