# I pip install a specific package with --global-option. How do I add that package as a dependency in setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, dulwich

I'm using this package called Dulwich. While developing, I install it like this:

```
pip install dulwich --global-option="--pure"
```

I want to add dulwich as a dependency to the setup.py file for my own package, but i'm not sure how to get it to use that pure flag. If my dependencies just looks like this:

```
DEPENDENCIES = [
    'dulwich',
]
setup(
    install_requires=DEPENDENCIES,
    ...
)
```

it will fail. I've tried all variations of adding --pure and --global-options but they all fail with errors like:

```
'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'--pure'"
```

How am I supposed to correctly add this package as a dependency? The end goal is that I can put my package on PyPi, so that when someone runs

```
pip install my_package
```

it will automatically run the equivalent of `pip install dulwich --global-option="--pure"` as well

Comment: I'd say this is impossible. There's a bunch of similar questions on SO: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161727/), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805385/), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045817), but no answer. I guess you could add a check in your setup script if the `--pure` global option was passed and abort the installation with a proper info message, but that's just it.